# Spliting string into a list of substrings

Tags: regex, r, string, substring, strsplit

I have a string `id <- "Hello these are words N12345678 hooray how fun"`.

I would like to extract just N12345678 from this string.

So far I have used `strsplit(id, " ")`. Now I have

```
>id
>[[1]]
>[1] "Hello" "these" "are" "words" "N12345678" "hooray" "how"
>[8] "fun"
```

Which is of type list and of length 1 (despite apparently having 8 elements?)

If I then use `id <- id[grep("^[N][0-9]",id)]`,
id is an empty list.

I think what I need to do is split the string into a list of length 8 with each element as a substring and then grep should be able to pick out the pattern, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: How about just `sub(".*(N\\d+).*", "\\1", id)`?

Comment: `gsub(".*(N[0-9]+).*","\\1",id)`
`[1] "N12345678"`

Comment: You could also try `unlist(strsplit(id, " "))` to make the data look nicer.

Comment: What you have is a list of one vector, and the vector has 8 elements. `id_list = strsplit(id, " ")`, then `length(id_list[[1]])`, or `grep("^[N][0-9]", id_list[[1]])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using `strsplit`. I think this can solve the problem:

```r
id <- "Hello these are words N12345678 hooray how fun"
id = strsplit(id, " ")
id[[1]][grep("^N[1-9]", id[[1]])]
```

Notice that I haven't changed your regex. It could be more precise expression such as `^N\\d+$`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `regmatches`

```
> regmatches(id, regexpr("N[0-9]+", id))
[1] "N12345678"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about strtok? It will parse your input line on certain characters. For the purpose of my example, I am breaking off a piece of my string every time I hit a space.

```
tempVar = strtok(string, " ");
// tempVar has "id" or everything up to the first space
while (tempVar != NULL)
{
     tempVar = strtok(NULL, " ");
     //now tempVar picked up the next word, and will loop picking up the next word until the end of string
}
```

Using this, your "Hello these are words N123456789 Hooray" would do this:
tempVar would be Hello, then "these" etc etc.

Each time through the loop tempVar would get a new value. So i would suggest evaluating tempVar in the loop (before grabbing the next one) so that you can stop when you have N123456789

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gsub('\\b[a-zA-Z]+\\b','',id)
```